# three dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want to store image pixels in a three-dimensional array and I did as :

```
public class ImageProcessing {
    private BufferedImage image;
    int p = image.getWidth();
    int q = image.getHeight();
    int r = 3;
    private int[][][] data = new int[p][q][r];
```

then i get the pixels value from that image and store it into that array and I make constructor as follows :

```
public ImageProcessing(BufferedImage img){
        image = img;
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
                int px = image.getRGB(x,y);
                int alpha = (px >> 24) & 0xFF;
                int red = (px >> 16) & 0xFF;
                int green = (px >> 8) & 0xFF;
                int blue = px & 0xFF;
                data[x][y][0] = alpha;
                data[x][y][1] = red;
                data[x][y][2] = green;
                data[x][y][3] = blue;
            }
        }
    }
```

then i want to retrieve it to convert the image into greyscale as follows:

```
public BufferedImage greyscale(){   
        for(int x = 0; x < p ; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < q ; y++){
                int avg = (data[x][y][1] + data[x][y][2] + data[x][y][3]/3);
                int grey = (data[x][y][0]<<24) + (avg<<16) + (avg<<8) + avg;
                image.setRGB(x, y, grey);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

But when I run it I shows error as follows I don't know what is it means and how to solve it ?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ImageProcessing.<init>(ImageProcessing.java:6)
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:14)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to solve it ? Any Idea ?

Comment: `int r=3` should be `int r=4` isn't it. Each color has 4 components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, It will because,

```
    private BufferedImage image;       // had not initialized image
    int p = image.getWidth();          // will be null
    int q = image.getHeight();         // same here
    int r = 3;
    private int[][][] data = new int[p][q][r];
```

You had not initialized `BufferedImage image` so, it will currently point to null, and when you initialize `p = image.getWidth();` and         `int q = image.getHeight();`, then do not have any values, so

`private int[][][] data = new int[p][q][r];`

This above statement will throw `NE`.

You should just declare array in Class, and should initialize it in constructor of your class with initializing `image`.

---

Edit:

Check out the below code, its initializing the `BufferedImage` and then doing the same, and its working fine !!

```
public class ArrayInitialize {
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        File file = new File("Image.jpg");
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(240, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int p = img.getWidth();          // will be null
        int q = img.getHeight();         // same here
        int r = 3;
        int count = 0;
        int[][][] data = new int[p][q][r];
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<q;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<r;k++){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

I think, after initializing the `BufferedImage` if your getting a `NullPointerException` then, there's some problem with your `getImage()` method, might be it's not working properly.

And See the comment

> int r=3 should be int r=4 isn't it. Each color has 4 components.

Comment: I have initialised the image as : GettingImage get = new GettingImage();
 private BufferedImage image = get.getImage(); after your answer. But the error is still as it is even the image is initialised any suggestion for it ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it out. And if it helped you then You can mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That 3 changing when 4, worked properly. Only the two things : r = 4 and initialisation of BufferedImage are my mistakes I accepted your answer.

Comment: This above statement will throw NE. hahhaa "NE"